# Displaying weird characters Turbo C++

Tags: c++

I have a little trouble in the display of heights for my program. This is what i wrote:

```
if (0 < LaserX < 161) {
LaserX = LaserX/n;
LaserY = LaserY/n;
sprintf(LaserMID, "%.1f, %.1f", LaserX, LaserY);
ShowCo->Text = LaserMID;
}
else { ShowCo->Text = 0; }
```

So basically it will show the height value when I have LaserX between 0 to 161, and anything out of that it shows 0. But in my case, when the LaserX value is out of the range, it shows me -NAN instead. What is -NAN?! How do i get rid of it?
Please advice, thnx.

Comment: NAN is "not a number". Your float value assumed a binary representation that doesn't correspond to any well-formed floating point number. This often happen because you did something wrong, like a zero-divide. Or you casted a integer that is an ill-formed floating point number to float.

Comment: @Ceztko: NaN is **not** an ill-defined binary pattern, on the contrary, it is a very well defined IEEE floating point value. It doesn't arise if "something goes wrong", either, but rather it is the result of particular arithmetic operations, such as 0/0, or for inverse trigonometric functions called on arguments outside their valid domain.

Comment: Add all the information you think is useful, but please be less abrupt as I don't think what I said is **wrong** with the bold. 1) There's no doubt there are many NaNs 2) It's debatable that a NaN it's a number in the "floating point numbers" domain. In any algebra, a set is determined only by the elements that respect useful properties, not by those that violates them. This doesn't mean you can't use NaN to signal special states in your specific problem. 3) Looking at the complexity of the question, I think saying that a NaN "often" arise from a mistake is correct.

Comment: I still dun quite get it, but I have modified the program as the Answers from everyone have given me, It doesnt show -NAN anymore but instead it affects my value of another variable in the front part of my program. In any case, is there a way I can use -NAN as a variable? E.g

Comment: if ( check == -NAN)
{
       --------------;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below condition is not what you want,

```
if (0 < LaserX < 161) // evaluated from left thus always true (which is unwanted)
```

You can change it to,

```
if (0 < LaserX && LaserX < 161)
```

It precisely means that `LaserX` is greater than `0` and less than `161`.

**Edit**: [NaN = Not a Number](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Infinity-and-NaN.html).

Comment: It is the same, but wat is -NAN means?

Comment: IT is the same as in my program stills gives me -NAN

Answer (score 3):

```
0 < LaserX < 161
```

Is wrong, as it is same as

```
(0 < LaserX) < 161
```

Which is always true as `(0 < LaserX)` goes to 1 or 0

You need

```
0 < LaserX && LaserX < 161
```

P.S.: Don't use Turbo C++... It is dead, outdated and should not be used

Comment: I have no choice but to use Turbo C++. Anyway, when i include this if/else in my program, it affects the upper part of my program. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

[NAN - not a number.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Change condition as in answers above. And problem will disappear.